# Call Custom Action from JavaScript in CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

maybe someone have experience to call custom action in JavaScript from CRM Online. I tried to follow many articles like [this](http://arpitmscrmhunt.blogspot.no/2015/03/dynamic-crm-2013-calling-custom-action.html)
but no luck i just receive error "Internal Serer Error". All this arcticles wtiten for on-promise so i think there is something special for CRM Online. I tried to use my Custom Action from workflow and there is everithing work fine. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to make correct SOAP message so i found framework that help me to work with Actions. I tested it and it works fine [Call Action in CRM 2015 Easily from JavaScript Library](http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2015/08/12/Call-Action-in-CRM-2015-Easily-from-JavaScript-Library)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have any issues with calling your Custom Action from JavaScript for CRM Online, as long as the JavaScript is running from within CRM.  If you're getting an Internal Server Error, then more than likely you have something wrong with your URL, or the SOAP message you're generating is invalid.  Generating SOAP in JavaScript is generally really ugly.